# Query all entries of the type "store" that have in the field "category" a link to an specific "id" in contentful

Tags: php, contentful

I want to query all entries of the type **"store"** that have in the field **"category"** at least one link with an specific **"id"**, how can I achieve this?

I tried that:

```
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query;
$query->setContentType('store')->where('fields.category.pt-BR', $id );
$page = $client->getEntries($query);
```

The structure of the link inside **"store"** is this:

```
["categories"]=>
object(stdClass)#49 (1) {
  ["pt-BR"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#52 (1) {
      ["sys"]=>
      object(stdClass)#55 (3) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(4) "Link"
        ["linkType"]=>
        string(5) "Entry"
        ["id"]=>
        string(22) "5LuXxFE2eQoqOY0yQO2iQ4"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the **"category"** itself looks like:

```
["category"]=>
  object(stdClass)#49 (1) {
    ["pt-BR"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#46 (1) {
        ["sys"]=>
        object(stdClass)#47 (3) {
          ["type"]=>
          string(4) "Link"
          ["linkType"]=>
          string(5) "Entry"
          ["id"]=>
          string(22) "5LuXxFE2eQoqOY0yQO2iQ4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query;
$query->setContentType('store')->where('fields.category.sys.id', $id );
$page = $client->getEntries($query);
```

or possibly:

```
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query;
$query->setContentType('store')->where('fields.category.pt-BR.sys.id', $id );
$page = $client->getEntries($query);
```

If you want it specifically for the `pt-BR` locale.

If you need to add a limit for the number of returned entry you can just append that:

```
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query;
$query->setContentType('store')->where('fields.category.pt-BR.sys.id', $id)->setLimit(5);
$page = $client->getEntries($query);
```

Consider that if you want the items returned in a predictable order you also need to add an order by to the query.

```
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query;
$query->setContentType('store')->where('fields.category.pt-BR.sys.id', $id)->setLimit(5)->orderBy('sys.createdAt');
$page = $client->getEntries($query);
```

If your `category` field is a list of values you can instead use the `in` selector like this:

```
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query;
$query->setContentType('store')->where('fields.category.pt-BR.sys.id', [$id], 'in')->setLimit(5)->orderBy('sys.createdAt');
$page = $client->getEntries($query);
```

For more information refer to: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/search-on-references

You can also very easily check the actual JSON response of a query in your browser by going to:

http://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/YOURSPACEID/entries/?access_token=YOURACCESSTOKEN&content_type=YOURCONTENTTYPEID&fields.category.sys.id=5LuXxFE2eQoqOY0yQO2iQ4

Comment: without the `->setContentType`? like this: `$query->where('fields.category.sys.id', $id );`

Comment: No, keep the setContentType, I'll clarify.

Comment: now the query is working, but is returning 1200+ lines, and was supposed to return 5 objects.

Comment: Just add a limit, updating my answer.

Comment: Consider using an order statement as well if you want a predictable result: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/order

Comment: the `setLimit` didn't work. I'm thinking now, that the "category" field in the "store" model is a reference to many ids, I thing I have to iterate the array and concat the results, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The easiest way would be to try to construct the query correctly in your browser. Then you can translate that into how you must construct it in PHP.

Comment: It looks like a simple task. In WordPress, one post can have more than one category, and I can easily find all the posts that have an specific category. Is the same case I'm having, put look's like is much more complex

Comment: Now I'm getting a 400 error resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: `{ "sys": { "type": "Error", "id": "InvalidQuery" }, "message": "The query you sent was invalid. Probably a (truncated...) '`

Comment: actually, the first query should probably work for an array of values as well. It's very hard to understand what's not working for you, could you provide an example of your content-model perhaps?

Comment: added an instruction how to retrieve the response directly from the CDN and inspecting it.